# CSS hovering with in a child div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the Background of body or parent div while hover a child div ?
How to change the background color of a parent div or the body part while hovering the text in a child div.
Give me the solution for this

.

.

Comment: Please give us the code you have tried. We need to know your HTML structure and relevant CSS to give you a definite answer (for example, it may be possible to use pseudo elements).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `:has` for this.

```css
.parent:has(.child:hover) { /* styles */
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `:has()` selector but it has limited  [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas())

```css
.parent{
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
}

.child{
  background: red;
}

.parent:has(.child:hover){
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  I am the parent
  <div class="child">
    I am the child
  </div>
</div>
```